# xslt - replace content by a reference when this content is shared by 2 files

Tags: xml, file, xslt

Given several XML files that I will call `source1.xml` that look like this for example (nodes may vary):

## Source files

```
<root id="s1">
    <title>example</title>
        <p>Some body text.</p>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Some list item</li>
                <li>Some list item</li>
            </ul>
            <p>qqwerty</p>
            <p>asdfg</p>
        </div>
</root>
```

## Reference files

And other files that I'll call `reference1.xml` that look like this:

```
<root>    
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Some list item</li>
            <li>Some list item</li>
        </ul>
        <p>qqwerty</p>
        <p>asdfg</p>
     </div>
<root>
```

And `reference2.xml` that looks like this:

```
<root>    
    <div>
       <p>Some body text.<p>
    </div>
</root>
```

There can only be one `div` element in each of these files.

## Mapping file

To map these together I have a file that looks like this:

```
<references>  
   <input src="source1.xml" id="s1">
      <reference>T:\temp\reference1.xml</reference>
      <reference>T:\temp\reference2.xml</reference>
   </input>
</references>
```

## Expected result

I would like to get the following:

```
<root id="s1">
    <title>example</title>
        <link href="reference2.xml"/>
        <div>
            <link href="reference1.xml"/>
        </div>
</root>
```

So the idea is that I want to see the whole content of the `div` node of `reference.xml` can be found AS/IS in `source.xml` and if so, just insert a reference to it in the source. It must a "dumb replace", if I find it, I replace it in the source, wherever the content might be, no matter of the parent element or whatever.

If only certain elements are found in the source, this is a no go, no link is created. It must be the exact same thing for a link to be created.

How do I do this with XSLT 2.0?

Right now, with the code suggested in the answer I get the following output:

```
<root id="s1">
    <title>example</title>
        <link href="reference2.xml"/>
        <div>
            <link href="reference1.xml"/>
            <link href="reference1.xml"/>
            <link href="reference1.xml"/>
        </div>
</root>
```

Instead of :

```
<root id="s1">
    <title>example</title>
        <link href="reference2.xml"/>
        <div>
            <link href="reference1.xml"/>
        </div>
</root>
```

Comment: I guess you want to use `deep-equal` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal to compare elements. It is currently not clear however if the `reference.xml` can contain multiple `ComponentDefinition` elements and if you want to replace any element or only certain (e.g. those inside of `div` elements). So you might want to edit your question and explain and/or show a more complete example. Also that `href="reference.xml"` does only show the file name, if you replace several items then the link would not identify an item.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your comment. I added some precisions. I am  not sure  I understand your comment about the file name though. What do you mean the link would not identify an item?  I guess it can be seen as an include. If the 2 files have the same content, then include the small file in the bigger file, sort of.

Comment: Well, the link points to the file and not to the element in the file. But if you have only one component in such a file then anyone using the link could of course use XPath to select the contents of the component so it is not a problem in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only a single element to be matched against then doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="ref-doc-uri" select="'reference.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-doc" select="doc($ref-doc-uri)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[deep-equal(., $ref-doc//ComponentDefinition/*)]">
        <link href="{$ref-doc-uri}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should suffice.

Based on your edit of the requirements I have enhanced the stylesheet as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="main-doc-uri" select="document-uri()"/>

    <xsl:param name="ref-list-doc-uri" select="'reference-list.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-list-doc" select="doc($ref-list-doc-uri)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="ref-docs" select="document($ref-list-doc/references/input[resolve-uri(@src) = $main-doc-uri]/reference)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="matched-doc" select="$ref-docs[ReusableComponent/ComponentDefinition/*[deep-equal(., current())]]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$matched-doc">
                <link href="{tokenize(document-uri($matched-doc), '/')[last()]}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where I assume that `reference-list.xml` has a structure like

```
<references>
    <input src="source1.xml">
        <reference>ref1.xml</reference>
        <reference>ref2.xml</reference>
    </input>
</references>
```

I haven't tried that code with several source and reference files, however, so you need to test yourself.

If there can be different namespaces used in the reference document then perhaps using a wild card helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="main-doc-uri" select="document-uri()"/>

    <xsl:param name="ref-list-doc-uri" select="'reference-list.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-list-doc" select="doc($ref-list-doc-uri)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="ref-docs" select="document($ref-list-doc/references/input[resolve-uri(@src) = $main-doc-uri]/reference)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="matched-doc" select="$ref-docs[*:ReusableComponent/*:ComponentDefinition/*[deep-equal(., current())]]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$matched-doc">
                <link href="{tokenize(document-uri($matched-doc), '/')[last()]}"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:next-match/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way, for the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root id="s1">
    <title>example</title>
    <p>Some body text.</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Some list item</li>
            <li>Some list item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</root>
```

I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root id="s1">
   <title>example</title>
   <link href="reference201605270302.xml"/>
   <div>
      <link href="reference201605270301.xml"/>
   </div>
</root>
```

The documents to be loaded are selected based on a comparison of the URIs in `resolve-uri(@src) = $main-doc-uri`, if you want to do that based on the `id` attribute then I guess you want `<xsl:variable name="ref-docs" select="document($ref-list-doc/references/input[@id = $main-doc/*/@id]/reference)"/>` with a global variable `<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>`.

Comment: This is brilliant, I would have not thought about this! Now is there a way for me to send the $ref by parameter from a for-each loop? (so no global variable)?

Comment: I am not sure where you want to use `for-each` instead of template matching. Do you have several reference files with components? You might need to edit your question and explain in more detail what kind of inputs you have.

Comment: Ok I've added more information. Sorry for the lack of info, I thought I could expand the answer to my actual situation.

Comment: @Flag, I have posted an extended version of the stylesheet that should show how to deal with a reference file mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's very interesting code, I've been tinkering with it for the last hour without success though. `Matched-doc` is always empty, I do not understand why.  I also do not understand how you can querry the content of `ref-docs` without calling the `document()` function?

Comment: As for `ref-docs`, it is a sequence of document nodes pulled in with the `document` function, as `<xsl:variable name="ref-docs" select="document($ref-list-doc/references/input[resolve-uri(@src) = $main-doc-uri]/reference)"/>` uses the document function. As for the problem with `matched-doc`, I think you need to show us what you have tried as probably the whole structure of the document I made up (`reference-list.xml`) is different. The only problems I had was that `deep-equal` with your samples only worked once I used `xsl:strip-space`.

Comment: Ok I think I know what's going on. I have a namespace int the reference files. the subelements that I need do not belong to it, but somehow the processor thinks they do because of the DTD or something. 
I'll find a way to get rid of these, thanks so much, you've been a fantastic help!

Comment: Just a note, after running the script without the namespace problem, I guess I get 1 "link tag" per element, not 1 for the whole bunch. strange.

Comment: I have tried to adjust the stylesheet a bit to your latest edit of the question, I hope you get it solved that way.

Comment: Hi again Martin, I've updated my question with the result I get thanks to you, unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to get exactly what I want. I'm starting to think XSLT is not the way to go. 
Do you have an idea about the update? Thanks

Comment: Well, you seem to have two different requirements, in one case you have a `<p>Some body text.</p>` in the input where you want to replace it if there is a `<div><p>Some body text.</p></div>` in the reference file. In the other case you have a a `<div>` with several child elements and you seem to want to replace its complete contents with a reference if the content matches. It is not clear to me when you want to implement the first and when the second requirement.

Comment: That's the thing, I dont know when some files will have one node to match as top element (this works with your solution), or if they have several nodes at the same level (duplicated insertions). Therefore i am not sure I can do this with XSLT. Mmh.