# XSLT - Deep equal unexpected behaviour

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Given file A that contains:

```
<body>
   <ul id="d76e10">         
      <li id="d76e11">Zoom In: Enlarges.</li>
      <li id="d76e13">Zoom Out: Reduces.</li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

File B that contains:

```
<body>
   <ul id="d78e10">
      <li id="d78e11"><uicontrol id="d78e12">Zoom In</uicontrol>: Enlarges.</li>
      <li id="d78e15"><uicontrol id="d78e16">Zoom Out</uicontrol>: Reduces.</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

And finally file C that contains:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Zoom In: Enlarges a section of the chart to show more detail.</p></li>
    <li>other stuff</li>      
  </ul>
</body>
```

I am trying to find identical `<li>` tags between File C and A or File C and B.

So basically, I have a do the following, according to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479600/xslt-replace-content-by-a-reference-when-this-content-is-shared-by-2-files):

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:variable name="matched-doc" 
      select="$ref-docs[//li[deep-equal(normalize-space(.), normalize-space(current()))]]" />
    <!-- ref-docs contains file A and B. -->
</xsl:template>
```

When I run this code, i get a positive hit for files A **and** B.
Clearly, it seems the normalize-space probably did something, because I have tried without and I get no hit, as expected.

Can anybody help me understand why the normalize-space seems to destroy child nodes?

Also, how can I have the Deep-equal function ignore the `ID` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `normalize-space` returns a primitive string value and comparing strings is of course different to comparing nodes.

As for ignoring attributes, you would need to transform your nodes first and remove the attribute(s) you want to ignore, then you can `deep-equal` compare the transformed nodes.

Or you could check whether your processor supports an extension with more control over the comparison, like http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/deep-equal.html, and the extension supports what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess I will have to write my own version of deep-equal!